# Initialize global variable outside&inside of definition

Tags: python-3.x

I'm studying transformer paper and there is a code implementation I found in HarvardNLP(link: http://nlp.seas.harvard.edu/2018/04/03/attention.html).

I know that when we want to change variable which is already initialized outside of a function, we should initialize it as a global variable inside of function.

```
x = 5
def foo():
    global x
    x = x * 2
    print(x)
foo()
```

But there are global initialization in the code below, which makes me confusing.

```
'''code link: http://nlp.seas.harvard.edu/2018/04/03/attention.html'''
global max_src_in_batch, max_tgt_in_batch
def batch_size_fn(new, count, sofar):
    "Keep augmenting batch and calculate total number of tokens + padding."
    global max_src_in_batch, max_tgt_in_batch
    if count == 1:
        max_src_in_batch = 0
        max_tgt_in_batch = 0
    max_src_in_batch = max(max_src_in_batch,  len(new.src))
    max_tgt_in_batch = max(max_tgt_in_batch,  len(new.trg) + 2)
    src_elements = count * max_src_in_batch
    tgt_elements = count * max_tgt_in_batch
    return max(src_elements, tgt_elements)
```

I expect global initialization out of the function let variables stay in our memory. Could anyone explain clearly what happened if I don't use global initialization outside of function?

Here is another code which uses the function.

```
class MyIterator(data.Iterator):
    def create_batches(self):
        if self.train:
            def pool(d, random_shuffler):
                for p in data.batch(d, self.batch_size * 100):
                    p_batch = data.batch(
                        sorted(p, key=self.sort_key),
                        self.batch_size, self.batch_size_fn)
                    for b in random_shuffler(list(p_batch)):
                        yield b
            self.batches = pool(self.data(), self.random_shuffler)

        else:
            self.batches = []
            for b in data.batch(self.data(), self.batch_size,
                                          self.batch_size_fn):
                self.batches.append(sorted(b, key=self.sort_key))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because, when you are in the function/subroutine/class interpreter doesn't know, that this particular variable refers to the global one, instead of the local one (cause you can have same variable name locally, and globally). So inside you also need to declare, that you will be calling global variable.

It isn't about memory, but more about reference...

Check the code below for example:

```py
>>> global x
>>> x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
>>> def foo():
...    x=1
...
>>> foo()
>>> x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
>>> def foo2():
...    global x
...    x=1
...
>>> x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
>>> foo2()
>>> x
1
```